# ROS isn't recognizing Create

Tags: ros, irobot-create, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

So I'm trying to run turtlebot with an irobot create, but whenever I run the minimal.launch file I get the following error/warning:

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1469047993.959124] Failed to contact device with error: [Error reading from SCI port. No data.]. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.

The create is on, plugged into the USB port, and the port path is /dev/tty/USB0. Any idea what the problem is? Is there some driver I need to install? I've heard it could be the battery but I haven't received any error messages regarding the battery being low.

Any answers are appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239958/ros-isn%27t-recognizing-create/) by [Breshnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/27552/breshnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you followed [these](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Create%20Base) steps too?

Basically, open the `.bashrc` file in your home directory and add

```
# Export the turtlebot variables
export TURTLEBOT_BASE=create
export TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles
export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=kinect
export TURTLEBOT_SERIAL_PORT=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

and also add your user to the dialout group:
`sudo adduser username dialout`, where `username` is your username.

---

Originally posted by [aguadopd](https://answers.ros.org/users/6283/aguadopd/) with karma: 86 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0